# What is the difference between 悩み and 疑問?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

On the Q&A site OKWAVE, it says that its purpose to help people resolve their questions and/or problems, and it uses [悩み](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E6%82%A9%E3%81%BF) and [疑問](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E7%96%91%E5%95%8F).

According to Weblio, 悩み has the meanings of “trouble(s), worry, distress; agony, anguish; a problem”, and 疑問 has the meanings of “(a) doubt; a problem, a question”.

Does anyone know the difference between these two terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant quote is shown and linked below:

[「教えて（質問）」と「答える（回答）」を仲介し、みなさまが抱えている疑問や悩み、望みを『OK』な状態にし、それを『Wave（波）』のように世界に広げていくという意味を社名にいただいております。](https://www.okwave.co.jp/about/)

The key meaning of 悩み is a worry; a concern. Distress and anguish are also listed as definitions. This is something that takes place in the mind of a person. It is an emotional response (occasionally a disorder) usually caused by anxiety due to improper grasp of or lack of information, though it need not necessarily be based in anything other people would consider reasonable or concrete.

The key meaning of 疑問 is a question; a doubt. When happening internally, this is something that would not necessarily have an emotional component, more a byproduct of the logical reasoning process or simple curiosity.

Simplifying the translation of the expression 疑問や悩み to 'questions and concerns' might make it more relatable.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I knew there had to be a difference between these two terms! (Smile)